# Expose DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

When developing WPF UserControls, what is the best way to expose a DependencyProperty of a child control as a DependencyProperty of the UserControl?  The following example shows how I would currently expose the Text property of a TextBox inside a UserControl. Surely there is a better / simpler way to accomplish this?

```xml
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <StackPanel Background="LightCyan">
            <TextBox Margin="8" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    
    namespace WpfApplication3
    {
        public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
        {
            public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
            public string Text
            {
                get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
                set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            }
    
            public UserControl1() { InitializeComponent(); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is how we're doing it in our team, without the RelativeSource search, rather by naming the UserControl and referencing properties by the UserControl's name.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1" x:Name="UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Background="LightCyan">
        <TextBox Margin="8" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=UserControl1}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Sometimes we've found ourselves making too many things UserControl's though, and have often times scaled back our usage. I'd also follow the tradition of naming things like that textbox along the lines of PART_TextDisplay or something, so that in the future you could template it out yet keep the code-behind the same.

Comment: this way works best in Silverlight 4 where there is no 'FindAncestor'

Comment: This worked for me, however it doesn't seem like you can use the same `x:Class` and `x:Name`.  I had to have a class like `WpfApplication1.SliderLabel` and I gave it a name like `SliderLabelControl`.  Otherwise it complained that the name already existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set DataContext to this in UserControl's constructor, then just bind by only path.

CS:

```
DataContext = this;
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Margin="8" Text="{Binding Text} />
```

Comment: this only works on a limited scale. if you really need a datacontext you're screwed