# Custom binding in Silverlight user control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, user-controls

I'm having issues Binding a custom User Control up through my ViewModel in an MVVM Silverlight  application. The basic control is a Date entry form with three text boxes. I am using the MVVM to get textbox data in three properties and then validate it to Date.

Binding Below control to MVVM works fine for me:

XAML of user Control:  **DateControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DatePicker.DateControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox MaxLength="2" TabIndex="0" Style="{StaticResource BirthDDTextBoxStyle}"
                                Text="{Binding BirthDay,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
                <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle_DateSeperator}"/>
                <TextBox MaxLength="2" TabIndex="1" Style="{StaticResource BirthDDTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding BirthMonth, Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
                <TextBlock   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle_DateSeperator}"/>
                <TextBox MaxLength="4" TabIndex="2" Style="{StaticResource BirthYYTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding BirthYear, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
                <Button Content="Show" Width="100" Height="30" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**DateControlViewModel**:

```cs
namespace DatePicker
{
    public class DatePickerViewModel : EntityViewModel
    {
        public DatePickerViewModel()
        {

        }

        private DateTime birthDate;
        public DateTime BirthDate
        {
            get
            {

                return birthDate;
            }
            set
            {
                birthDate = value;
            }
        }
        private string birthDay;
        public string BirthDay
        {
            get { return birthDay; }
            set
            {
                birthDay = value;
                PropertyChangedHandler("BirthDay");
                ValidateBirthDay("BirthDay", value);
            }
        }

        private string birthMonth;
        public string BirthMonth
        {
            get { return birthMonth; }
            set
            {
                birthMonth = value;
                PropertyChangedHandler("BirthMonth");
                ValidateBirthMonth("BirthMonth", value);
            }
        }

        private string birthYear;
        public string BirthYear
        {
            get { return birthYear; }
            set
            {
                birthYear = value;
                PropertyChangedHandler("BirthYear");
                ValidateBirthYear("BirthYear", value);
            }
        }

        private void ValidateDOB()
        {
            ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthDay");
            ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthMonth");
            ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthYear");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthDay))
                ValidateBirthDay("BirthDay", BirthDay);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthMonth))
                ValidateBirthMonth("BirthMonth", BirthMonth);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthYear))
                ValidateBirthYear("BirthYear", BirthYear);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthDay) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthMonth) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(BirthYear))
                SetDateOfBirth();
        }

        private void ValidateBirthDay(string propertyName, string value)
        {
            ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.EmptyDayMessage");
            else
                if (Common.IsNumber(value))
                {
                    int day = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    if (day > 31 || day < 1)
                        AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidDayMessage");
                }
                else
                    AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidDayMessage");
        }

        private void ValidateBirthMonth(string propertyName, string value)
        {
            ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.EmptyMonthMessage");
            else
                if (Common.IsNumber(value))
                {
                    int month = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    if (month > 12 || month < 1)
                        AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidMonthMessage");
                }
                else
                    AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidMonthMessage");
        }

        private void ValidateBirthYear(string propertyName, string value)
        {
            ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.EmptyYearMessage");
            else
                if (Common.IsNumber(value))
                {
                    int year = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    if (year.ToString().Length > 4 || year.ToString().Length < 4)
                        AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidYearMessage");
                }
                else
                    AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidYearMessage");
        }

        private void SetDateOfBirth()
        {
            string dateString = BirthDay + "-" + BirthMonth + "-" + BirthYear;
            DateTime date;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString.ToString(), out date))
            {
                ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthDay");
                ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthMonth");
                ClearErrorFromProperty("BirthYear");
                AddErrorForProperty("BirthDay", "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidDayMessage");
                AddErrorForProperty("BirthMonth", "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidMonthMessage");
                AddErrorForProperty("BirthYear", "Resources.PatientImport.InvalidYearMessage");
            }
            else
                BirthDate = date;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this control in my **MainPage.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DatePicker.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatePicker"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <local:DateControl />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**I want to define a Property in DateControl which I will use to bind my UserControl with ViewModel of MainPage.xaml**

Something like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <local:DateControl Date="{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
</Grid>
```

**BirthDate is string Type Property.**

**How do I change my usercontrol so I can bind its property in MainPage.XAML using separate MVVM**

Comment: You should read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), the formatting was quite broken...

Comment: Check this answer out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412/expose-dependencyproperty

Comment: Why have you added the Date property to your UserControl? Views can exist without code at all, everything can be done using only view models.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the `DataContex`t of your `DateControl` to the `DateControlViewModel`. In your `DateControl` xaml you can use this idea, or set it somewhere in code (like a constructor of the `DateControl`) or data bind the `DataContext` to the view model you want to use.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewModels:ViewDisplayTemplatesViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModel}"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

Secondly, you need to define a dependency property in your `DateControl`, as Aardvark mentioned in the comment. I use the propdp snippet (which I think comes with the Silverlight install, if not you can see it in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). The Dependency property enables binding in xaml.